# Assign textfield value to an array even after changing the value swift

Tags: arrays, swift, duplicates, append, textfield

I have a textfield and i want to store the textfield value to an array, so that i can pass this string to the API request.
The textfield value is fetched using the textfield delegate method and it is as follows:

```
var phoneNo = [String]()
 

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            
            switch textField {
            
            case contact_PhoneNumberTextField:
                guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
                let newString = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
                textField.text = formatPhoneNumber(phoneString: newString)
                return false
            
            default:
                return true
            }
            
        }
    
      func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    
            if textField == contact_PhoneNumberTextField{
                
                phoneNo.append(getOriginalPhoneNumber(phone: textField.text ?? ""))
            }
    }
```

The problem is with appending the textfield to phoneNo array.The textfield value is initially stored to an array.Suppose if i change the value of the same textfield, then it will create one more value in the array, instead i want to replace the same value in the array to avoid creating multiple values in the array.How can that be achieved?

Comment: You will need to keep track of what object you are changing, maybe by keeping track of its index in the array or the original value so you can find and replace it with the edited value

Comment: Why are you appending.?Just replace the whole string.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Could you please let me know what needs to be done?

Comment: After reading the comment from @Rob I now see you don’t have an array but a string to store your values in so my previous comment is not really relevant anymore. Given this and the comment below I am convinced you need to rethink your whole solution. Maybe you should take the time to create a custom struct to hold the values of your text fields

Answer (score 0):

As @Rob mentioned, `phoneNo` is a String, and like array, it has `append` in Swift but it doesn't mean you need to use that. If `phoneNo` can have only one value e.g "04111111111", then just replace the new one with the old one!

Sth like this:

```
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == contact_PhoneNumberTextField{
            phoneNo = getOriginalPhoneNumber(phone: textField.text ?? "")
        }
   }
```

FYI:

[image]

Comment: I want to store it in an array because there are many textfields and their values.If the first textfield is stored in array and if i change the first textfield value again, then the stored value should also be replaced.